# How to determine which TTY channel is mapped to specific USB port

Tags: ubuntu, tty, ttyusb

I have a very specific question. On my laptop with only USB and no RS232, I can see which bus & port I’m on but I haven’t been able to find the command that tells me which tty channel it is mapped to. Even my Linux teacher doesn’t know it.

Can you help me?

David

Comment: `dmesg | grep tty` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
  ls -l /dev/serial/by_path
```

will show you sym-links that you can use to connect to a serial port if you know which usb socket it is plugged into, or can interptret to determin the usb path to your serial port.

eg:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jan 27 10:08 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Equally `/dev/serial/by-id` may help if there's a chance for USB dongles to be plugged into different physical sockets.

Comment: It may, but many brands of dongles don't ship with unique IDs (FTDI being the notable exception)

Answer (score 0):

My Linux teacher pointed me in the direction of minicom. 
Now I just need to understand how to interface with minicom. 
 YouTube here I come.